# System WebView crash CKEditor

Tags: android, webview, ckeditor

After update Android System WebView, I cannot upload image file on CKEditor.
But, I did uninstall updates Android System WebView, image can be uploaded normally.
Is there a way to use upload image on CKEditor without uninstall updates Android System WebView?